# A good football match ON(preposition at the end meaning)

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of the **''on''** at the end of this sentence:

> Question: How often do you watch TV?
>
> Answer(native): ''I'd say maybe only a few times a month when there is a good football match **on**''

Is this the same as:

> "I'd say maybe only a few times a month when there is a good football match **on** TV".(my understanding)
>
> Does this mean that the above answer just omit the ''TV'' word because he's a native speaker, thinking it can still be understood because he said **''on''** at the end of his answer?

Are they the same?

Comment: Yes. It means "on TV."

Comment: See the verb "be on"

Comment: @V.V.: it says ''appear on TV or radio''. Can it also be used **"on the internet''**? Is this ON fixed only on TV/radio?

Comment: @JohnArvin: We wouldn't say it was "on" in that context. "On" means airing at a certain time as part of a broadcast schedule. It could still be "on the Internet" but that is not precisely the same thing.

Comment: What? what should it be then?